# Attunity Replicate - tables in Azure are created without clustered indexes

Tags: replication, azure-sql-database, attunity

I have a large(~33 millions records) on-premise SQL Server database which must be replicated to an SQL Azure database (near-realtime replication is required).
I'm trying to use Attunity Replicate software to achieve this.

I created a task with `Full Load` option specified which successfully uploaded initial data to Azure.
After that I created another Task with `Apply Changes` option specified, but this task ends with errors:

```
Failed to execute statement: 'INSERT INTO [attrep_apply_exceptions] values ( ...'

RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 42000 NativeError: 40054 Message: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server] Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again. Line: 1 Column: -1
```

Attunity created `[attrep_apply_exceptions]` table in the Azure database which doesn't have any clustered index, so insert fails (Azure doesn't allow tables without clustered index).

Why is it happening? Should I add an index myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [sql-azure](/questions/tagged/sql-azure) tables must have a clustered index. You will be able to create a table without one but once you insert your first record you will see the message:`Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server`

There is a list of Azure Sql limitations/differences [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336245.aspx#cir)

To answer your question, yes you must add a clustered index yourself.